# Facebook's in-app browser

Tags: facebook, browser, cross-browser

When I click a link in the android/iOS facebook app, what is the browser that opens? Is it facebook's own browser? Do I need to start worrying about comparability with it along with the usual Firefox/Chrome/IE trio?

Google results on this question are surprisingly thin.

Thanks!

Comment: Apple's iOS review guidelines prohibit using rendering engines other than the provided WebKit view, so on iOS it'd have to be that. I'd guess that they'd be using the built in web view on Android too.

Answer (score -1):

Yes & yes!  This is the new Facebook "in-app" browser.  I agree, for such a widely used browser now, there is very little information available.

Comment: Not sure what you're really adding here as an answer. As @PartiallyFinite has commented, Facebook have to use Webkit in iOS. I doubt it's a new browser, it's probably using either WKWebView or UIWebview underneath just to keep you in the app.